# Take rest (non countable)

Tags: grammar

Go home and take ( ) rest.

I guess people usually say "take a rest", but But is it also ok to use "rest" non-countably?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rest" can be treated as a countable or non-countable noun.

"Go take a rest." This sentence treats "rest" as countable: the speaker is talking about having a specific session of rest (a break).

"I need rest from this job." This sentence treats "rest" as non-countable: the speaker wants to have some kind of rest, but isn't talking about a specific instance of rest. It is more general than the countable form.

"Some rest" is also common, and can refer to a specific instance of rest or rest in general depending on the context.
"Get some rest for tonight." This refers to sleeping that night, so it is specific.
"Lately, I rarely get to take some rest from taking care of my brother." This refers to rest in general, over many instances.